# Password works when logging in but not in terminal

Tags: system-installation

I just installed ubuntu and when I made my password i forgot to turn num lock back on. So when i log into my account i can do so but when i go to terminal it doesn’t work. I think the reason is the numlock but now I’m unsure as to what I should do

Answer (score 0):

See [Link](https://itsfoss.com/change-password-ubuntu/) for how to change password.  See [Link](https://itsfoss.com/root-user-ubuntu/) for information on root user and password.
If you can't find the root password, you will have to re-install ubuntu.

If you are unsure of what you are enterring, you can type your password in a text editor and copy paste it in the terminal. Use your mouse to do so since ctrl-v is seen as an entry.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way:

Use the GUI to change the password to any value you want. You can access this via the icon in the top right corner of your screen.